# Python: Is it possible to call a method from a 'sibling' class?

Tags: python, oop

I have done a bit of research and I can't seem to find an answer, maybe I missed something obvious.

So, if I have a class named *'Base'* and two classes: *'A'* and *'B'* inherit from it, can I call a method from class *'B'* within class *'A'*?

Comment: No. You inherit only from the parent, not from your siblings.

Comment: Sounds like a design-flaw.

Comment: Out of interest - if you need a method accessible from both A and B, why wouldn't you put it in Base?

Comment: Any code can call a method from class `B`, as long as it's calling it on a `B` object. It doesn't need to be a sibling class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, so long as you're applying it to an object of type **B**.  This means that you'd need something like

```
Class A(parent):
    ...

def sibling_rivalry(self, B_object):
    ...
    B_object.B_method()
```

You *cannot* apply a method of type **B** to an object of type **A**.  For instance, in the above method **sibling_rivalry**,

```
    self.B_method()
```

is simply not a valid reference.

Comment: While you can do this, we would have to question the wisdom of this design.

Comment: That depends on the application.  I've had designs with interactions among related items, in which I needed to grab information from a support object.  In most cases, it's better to put such a method in the parent class, but ... well, teammates can decide otherwise.  :-)

Comment: The fact that the classes are siblings is irrelevant in the first case. Any code can call `B_Object.B_method()`

Comment: Right.  Just trying to anticipate what OP might be trying to accomplish.

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.